# Why can't umbreon use moon blast?

Tags: pokemon

Umbreon is "the moonlight pokémon" but it can't use moonblast. Why not? Shouldn't umbreon be able too?

Comment: He is regarded as "the moonlight pokemon", but he's still a Dark type. He's also much more of a support Pokemon than an attacker.

Comment: IS this a TV canon question (on topic) or a video game question (off topic)?

Comment: Probably the latter. It doesn't reference any TV scene. A Pokemon's learnset is strictly a game mechanic first and foremost, but also non-permanent lore second. This is a question on the in-universe reason behind a particular point of the game's design. As such, I don't recommend closing this question. At the most, transfer it to video games SE.

Comment: TV canon or video game canon doesn't make a difference. Both are science fiction and as such valid (since it's not about specific game mechanics, quests, etc.).

Comment: Downvoted because it is clearly a question about the game mechanics. In the anime, Pokemon learn whatever move they want when its convenient for the plot.

Answer (score 7):

[Moonblast](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moonblast_%28move%29) is a fairy-type attack and [Umbreoun](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Umbreon) ain't no [fairy-type](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fairy_%28type%29) pokemon, he's a [dark-type](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dark_%28type%29) pokemon.

[image: Moonblast]

Although historically attack types have tended to make logical sense (all the characters that can use Punch have fists, for example), more recently they've simply followed the type. Espeon, for example is the "sunlight" pokemon but doesn't have "Solar blast".

Comment: The fact that he is Dark and not Fairy does not inherently preclude him from having/using Fairy moves. Both Moonlight and Charm can be learned/bred.

Comment: It doesn't preclude it, but nor does it mean that he has to have it. There are numerous odd choices in Pokemon, including the fact that numerous pokemon can learn horn drill despite not having a horn

Comment: @phantom42 [Who can learn what has never made sense](http://i302.photobucket.com/albums/nn115/Anime_Kid_Originals/Poke6-1.png)

Comment: @Izkata - There's a whole bunch of these; http://bmgf.bulbagarden.net/f323/move-inconsistencies-86921/

Comment: Yeah i guess so but it would be nice if umbreon did have moon blast wouldn't it...

Comment: @user21723 - As someone who doesn't play pokemon, I have very few feelings on the subject.

Comment: Also to add to the mix, despite Eevee evolving with stones in the first generation and Espeon and Umbreon being the Sun and Moon Pokemon, respectively, neither evolves with the Moon or Sun stone.

Comment: @TheUnknownDev Generally, when a new evolution is added to an existing Pokémon, that evolution is triggered using a mechanic that wasn't available in the previous games, in order to a) showcase and utilise that mechanic, and b) explain why that evolution wasn't availably before. That's the case with Espeon and Umbreon: they take advantage of the day/night and friendship mechanics that were added in Gen II.

Comment: For the record, it's worth noting that Alolan Muk is Poison/Dark and, in *Pokémon Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee*, can learn Moonblast.